# How to use varied funtions?

Tags: python, function

l am trying to make a program that runs with the following definitions but when l run the code l get recursion error and l was wondering if someone could help on why this happens and how to fix it.

If x >= 0, then absolute value to x identical with x

If x < 0, then absolute value - x absolute value shall always be positive)

```
def absol(x):
    if x>=0:
          return absol(x)
    elif x<=0:
        return absol(x)

    
print("absolute value to 5 is", absol(5))
print("absolute value to -3 is", absol(-3))
print("absolute value to 0 is", absol(0))
absol()
```

Comment: When did you expect it to stop recursing?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I want the program to print the three print sentences at the bottom, but l am not sure how l can edit the program to only do it once.

Comment: Yes, I understand the output you want, but what you've _written_ does the same thing in either case: call the function recursively with the same argument it just received. Which will do the same thing in either case: call the function recursively with...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not reflect the logic you outline in prose. You could do the following if you insist on a recursive approach:

```
def absol(x):
    if x >= 0:     # base case is needed
        return x   # that does NOT recurse
    else:
        return absol(-x)  
        # argument must be different for the recursive call
        # so you can reach the base case eventually
```